# Don' t cache in ie10 and ie11

Tags: internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache, offline-caching

I have a source code use manifest. When i run code in chorme it work. But when i run in ie 10 AppCache Fatal Error.
Code html:

```
<html manifest="demo.manifest">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p id="timePara"><button onclick="getDateTime()">Get Date and Time</button></p>

    <p><img src="imgs/img_logo.gif" width="336" height="69"></p>

    <p>Try opening <a href="tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm" target="_blank">this page</a>, then go offline, and reload the page. The script and the image should still work.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And code manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
    js/demo_time.js
    imgs/img_logo.gif
```

Some body help me. Thank you for support.

Comment: You don't appear to declare jquery as part of your manifest?

Comment: @RowlandShaw please explaning clear. I don't  understand.

Comment: Your HTML file references js/jquery.min.js, but your manifest references js/demo_time.js